# NVM Storage Simulator in Linux/C++

Tags: c++, linux, database, storage, nvm

I am currently working on porting a project to run on Linux, which was storing some data in a NVM external storage. On my hardware I only have at my disposal an eMMC main storage where the Linux rootfs lays. What I would like to do is to simulate the previous NVM external storage in Linux so that my application can store some data there.

The first obvious solution that crossed my mind was to store this data in a different memory area in the eMMC which is not used by linux but currently I don't have control over partitioning the current layout of the eMMC.

Another idea that crossed my mind was to store this data in a file on the fs but this will introduce a lot of opening and closing the fd for writing and getting the data, apart that the file can get corrupted easily.

Side notes: the application I'm trying to port is written in C++.

What I would like to find out by asking this question here is not how to specifically implement this but rather finding out different solution and ideas to solving this.

More info about the application and requirements:

- Data that needs to be stored is probably less than 5 mb
- The data needs to be written as fast as possible and I'm not sure about how much data needs to be written but I would guess at this point to be 20kb/s
- Related to the old implementation, I don't have access anymore to that, I only have a simple interface to use so I can't say anything about the features that the old NVM used. To start with I would like to have something simple that works without any bells and whistles
- What I do have is a mapping for every data entry that I want to store with the proper memory offset from a base address.

Thanks.

Comment: You should add more details how exactly the NVM is used by your application, how much data is stored, how often will it be modified. Did the old NVM implementation implement wear levelling? Is it a requirement that modified data gets written as fast as possible or can you delay the writing? Is the system capable of detecting a power loss? In this situation,is there enough time to write the modified data?

Comment: @Bodo added some more info, thanks for the input

Comment: I think the information about your requirements is still not detailed enough for reasonable recommendations. In a Linux system with a filesystem it might even be better to store the data in a different way instead of emulating some "NVM" which might have been the only option in the old system. An interface where you have to handle address offsets in one big block might not be very efficient. You should define what types of data you have and how often which data gets changed. Are there data with different importance? Showing some code how you use the old NVM interface might also be useful.

Comment: @Bodo unfortunately showing some code is not an option, I don't have any more information to go forward, in the old implementation I assume there was a big memory block in which the data was written and read (I don't have any more info on this because I don't have the source files.) but if we leave the NVM aside for one moment, what are some good ideas to store some data, in linux, preferably userspace, with fast access for writing and reading keeping in mind that the device is not able to detect power loss

Comment: Without sufficient requiremes you will probably not get a good answer or no answer at all. Some general hints: Think about your requirements and write them down. What data do you have, when/how often do you need/want to read and/or write the data? What happens if the data gets lost or is outdated? Use a journalling file system if possible. To make sure you always have either old valid data or new valid data you can write the data to a temporary file followed by an atomic rename. Maybe you can use RTLinux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up opening/creating a file on the file system

```
memFileFd = open(memFilePath.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, (mode_t)0600);
```

Expanding the file to the desired size

```
// go to the end of the desired size
lseek(memFileFd, memSize, SEEK_SET);

// write termination character to expand it
write(memFileFd, "", 1);
```

Map the memory allocated for the file

```
memBlock = (uint8_t *)mmap(0, memSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memFileFd, 0);

// we can safely close the FD now after the mem was mapped
close(memFileFd);
```

Then we can write and read from the block of memory and treat it as a virtual NVM

```
// write data
memcpy(memBlock + address, bufferToBeWritten, bufferLength);

// we want to flush the cached pages touched by us so we
// calculate the start address of the cache page written and the
// size of the touched memory as a multiple of page size
int pagesize = getpagesize();
uint32_t syncStartPageOffset = (address / (uint32_t)pagesize) * pagesize;
uint32_t syncSize = ((bufferLength / (uint32_t)pagesize) + 1) * pagesize;

// sync mem
msync(m_memBlock + syncStartPageOffset, syncSize, MS_SYNC);

// read data
memcpy(bufferToBeReadIn, memBlock + address, bufferLength);
```